# Windows 8 mouse driver to use laptop touchpad for touch input?

Tags: windows-8-preview

As Windows 8 is built for touch, some games such as Violet Storm in App Store doesn't work well whith mousepad on laptops. Is there any driver that can turn this mouse pad to position sensing or something like that so that I can play the game nicely.